# Multiple legends in same spplot

Tags: r, plot, legend, r-sp

i want to plot a map where i have two variables. One is a polygon and other is a point.

polygon -  Province boundary (name1, name2, name3, name4 ),

point   -  class (a, b, c, d)

since i have to plot them together i need two legends. below is the code where i get legend for polygon feature. Please suggest how can add the legend for point feature as well.

```
  #importing shp files
 states = readOGR ( dsn = "C:/.../shp", layer = "states")
 river = readOGR ( dsn = "C:/.../shp", layer = "Province")
 stations = readOGR ( dsn = "C:/.../shp", layer = "ganga_stations_prj")

r <-list("sp.lines", river, pch = 10, cex= 2, col = "blue" ) # line feature



map = function(x, ...)
{

 scale = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.scale.bar(), 
 offset = c(800000, 2480000), scale = 300000, fill=c("transparent","black"))
 text1 = list("sp.text", c(800000,2520000), "0")
 text2 = list("sp.text", c(1100000, 2520000), "200 km")
 arrow = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.north.arrow(), 
 offset = c(1800000,3300000), scale = 100000)

spplot(states, "NAME_1",  sp.layout=list(scale,text1,text2, arrow, r, x),main = "Human Use Classification")

}



stations@data$Colour[stations@data$Class=="a"]="yellow"
stations@data$Colour[stations@data$Class=="b"]="green"
stations@data$Colour[stations@data$Class=="c"]="blue"
stations@data$Colour[stations@data$Class=="d"]="red"

p <-list("sp.points", stations,pch=18, cex=1.5, col=stations@data$Colour)
map(p)
```

Map i get:

[image]

As you can see there is legend only for PROVINCE (polygon)  .how can  i add it for point feature as well ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with spplot, but normally you can use legend:

```
legend("bottomright", legend=c("a","b","c","d"), pch=18, col=c("yellow","green","blue","red"))
```

Comment: does legend() work with spplot(). it is giving error:plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: `legend()` is for base graphics; `spplot()` uses the `grid`-based `lattice`-package

Comment: @Rbeginner Try starting with "plot.new()", then draw your map, then call the legend command. (I work with ggplot a lot, also grid-based, there it works).

Answer (score -1):

Try `legend.grid()` function from the package `grid`. It worked for me and thank you for putting this up.